# How to check if composer's autoloader is being used?

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I'm developing a certain PHP framework for WordPress, and I want to give my users the option to use composer to install it as a package, or to install it manually. If composer is used, then a `psr-4` class autoloader handles everything. If not, then all files must be loaded manually during the framework's bootstrapping process.

Is there a safe way to check whether composer's autoloader is being used in a given WordPress environment?

Currently i'm using:

```
if( !class_exists('Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader') )
{
    // Manually include files if composer is not used.
    require_once 'some/files.php';
}
```

However, if in a given WordPress environment there is a plugin that uses composer internally, then the above if statement will return `true` even though other plugins have no access to it.

Comment: Is the 'global' composer auto loader location in a repeatable place?

Comment: @RobertDeBoer no, it's not. It can exist in multiple locations at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, as it turns out, is quite simple. You need to create 2 different bootstrapping files, say `manual-bootstrap.php` and `composer-bootstrap.php`. Then add the following lines to `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["composer-bootstrap.php"]
}
```

`composer-bootstrap.php` will only be called if composer is used to load the framework as a dependency. Users that want to load the framework manually will use `manual-bootstrap.php` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(class_exists("\Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader"))
{
  // a composer autoload.php has already been included/required
}
```